# Flash HTTP requests URL containing RTMPE URL. How do I trick it to get a local copy or a copy with my content?

Tags: php, html, flash, greasemonkey

A web channel streaming service streams to a certain IP range, it only checks the IP in example.com/cmd.php?id=xxx (channel number) and outputs an rtmpe stream URL, nothing else.

How do I trick it to get my local URL instead of the one on their server? I have considered squid proxy, but is there some way to do it with a firefox plugin or greasemonkey script?

It's hard to explain in shot text, so feel free to ask. Sorry if it made no sense.

Also, I'm new to stackoverflow, please bear with me, and feel free to tell me if my question is not allowed here.

Thank you.

Edit:
I will try to specify:
It's a streaming service from an ISP and cable provider.

They stream for free to people on their IP's. On their webtv page, which is called webtv.example.com, there is a flash player. If you are not on an IP from their ISP, you can't stream anything but the test channel.

When you try to change channel via. javescript:videoplayer_changechannel(xxx) it makes this HTTP request:

```
GET https://removed.com/cmd.php?sid=XXX&cmd=get%5Fserver [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 88ms]
```

If you are on one of their IP's you will get an RTMP URL, like this:

```
servers=rtmpe://removed*.dk/live/;&profile=6&filename=*removed*.stream
```

This is what the flash player requests, and if it get's this response it load the channel requested. There is no HTML on the php page, just the URL. Note that the rtmp URL is static.

If you are not on one of their IP's it will return a random sentence (something stupid, the programmers having fun).

I wan't to trick the flash player into getting the right value, even though it's not on one of the ISP's IP's.

I would like to know if this is possible with a browser plugin or script.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the [Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) for FireFox if you wanted. This would allow you to edit the HTML (provided the page doesn't use frames). Though this would only be useful if the URL is actually stored on the page.

If the URL is stored in JavaScript then you could just type in `javascript:varName = 'myurl';` in your URL bar and that'll update the JavaScript for you.

If it's a flash based streaming service then your easiest method is the proxy that you've got running at the moment.

I'm sorry if this answer isn't good for you - but it's hard to provide an answer without studying the site your questioning about.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have edited my post with more detail.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of then is if you decompile the flash movie and change the script so that rather than loading the RTMP URL from `https://removed.com/cmd.php?sid=XXX&cmd=get%5Fserver` you just simply hard code `rtmpe://removed*.dk/live/;&profile=6&filename=*removed*.stream` as the URL.